# xamarin geolocation uncaught exception occurs

Tags: xamarin.forms

I use Xamarin geolocation in my project. When I test the application in the simulator
`cannot throw 'plugin.geolocator.abstractions.Geolocationexception on thread 1` and does not return values.

```
var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
locator.DesiredAccuracy = 20;
var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(timeout: 
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10000));
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please add enough details so that other users can replicate your situation. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You should add permission in your iOS and Android project.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the iPhone Simulator, you need to simulate a location.

In the simulator menu select Debug > Location, and make sure you have a location set.

Here is the [documentation](https://github.com/xamarin/recipes/tree/master/Recipes/ios/multitasking/test_location_changes_in_simulator)